# What is the probability function of the sum of $N$ categorical distribution experiments

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a categorical distribution defined by

$$P(X)=0.5\delta(X+1)+0.25\delta(X)+0.25\delta(X-1).$$

Suppose I want to repeat the experiment $N$ times and sum all the $X$ values

The resulting value would fit another categorical distribution with $2N+1$ coefficients.

Is there any analytical way to calculate them? Brute forcing through code is quite trivial, but that is not the approach I'm looking for.

Comment: what do you mean by 'fit another distribution'? Do you mean approximate, like Student's t-distribution and Normal, or define, like sum of Bernoulli's sum to Binomial, or converge, like Geometric to Exponential?

Comment: @Alex The simplest case would be for N=2, where the possible results would be -2, -1, 0, 1, 2. It would be a categorical distribution for those possible outcomes. What I want is the probability of each of those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get what I think you want is to use the probability generating function of the individual distribution:

$$
F(z) = \sum_k p_k z^k = \frac12 z^{-1} + \frac14 + \frac14 z
$$

Then the probability generating function for the sum of $n$ such i.i.d. variables is

$$
G_n(z) = [F(z)]^n
$$

For instance, with $n = 3$ variables, the sum is distributed as

\begin{align}
G_3(z) & = [F(z)]^3 \\
       & = \left( \frac12 z^{-1} + \frac14 + \frac14 z \right)^3 \\
       & = \frac18 z^{-3} + \frac{3}{16} z^{-2} + \frac{9}{32} z^{-1}
         + \frac{13}{64} + \frac{9}{64} z + \frac{3}{64} z^2 + \frac{1}{64} z^3
\end{align}

meaning that the sum has the distribution

$$
\text{sum} = \begin{cases}
    -3 & \text{with probability $1/8$} \\
    -2 & \text{with probability $3/16$} \\
    -1 & \text{with probability $9/32$} \\
     0 & \text{with probability $13/64$} \\
     1 & \text{with probability $9/64$} \\
     2 & \text{with probability $3/64$} \\
     3 & \text{with probability $1/64$}
\end{cases}
$$

---

ETA: This formulation doesn't give you the specific probabilities in any magical way beyond an exhaustive case analysis, but it does permit one to organize those cases in an effective way, especially if code is being written.  (You could use FFT.)  It can give things like expressions for the various moments.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to know